# What does “x” character represent in android versions?

Tags: android, android-version

In this official Android source page (https://source.android.com/setup/start/build-numbers) that contains the code names, API levels and versions numbers some of the versions contain the character x in its version number for example:

- Froyo: the version number  is 2.2.**x**
- Honeycomb: the version number is 3.2.**x**

So what does x character represents in the version numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the "x" stands for all the versions for the specified version. For example, `2.2.x` stands for `2.2.1`, `2.2.2`, and `2.2.3`.

[Wikipedia page for the different Android versions.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history)

Answer (score 1):

It is the API coverage.

As an example:
Honeycomb Versions start from 3.0 to 3.2.6.

3.0 API 11

3.1 API 12, NDK6

3.2.x means that all versions starts with 3.2 are API 13. Also x is the patch level of API 13 for honeycomb.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, 
X is mean all of something. Like 3.0.x mean all of 3.0.1,3.0.2,etc. And new version update of android studio, we got. androidX. I guess its mean, They put all feature of pre version in one.

Answer (score 0):

The X in the **Version Number** suggests the **Patch Update** version. The First number stands for the **Android Version Start (i.e 3 for HoneyComb and moving forward)**, the Second Number stands for the **Sub-Android Version of the Base Version(i.e. 3.1)** and the X then stands for the **Patch Update Number(3.1.1)**.